# if "id" parameter exists in url its taking to redirect url and if "id" parameter is not exists in url its not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I have some code, in that first if statement URL is redirected successfully if the "id" parameter is available in URL.
If the "id" parameter is removed it's giving a blank page.
Will below else if statement works?

/* Actual one */

```
if(incomingPayload && incomingPayload.id && incomingPayload.id != 12345){
        incomingPayload.id = 12345;
}
```

**Fixed one**

```
      if(incomingPayload && incomingPayload.id && incomingPayload.id != 12345){
            incomingPayload.id = 12345;
            console.log('first if statement');
        }
        else if (incomingPayload || incomingPayload.id || incomingPayload.id == "") {
            incomingPayload.id = 12345;
            console.log('second if staement', incomingPayload.id )
        }
```

I want to redirect if "id" params are not mentioned in URL

Comment: `!incomingPayload.id` means id is not set.

Comment: so how can i change my code

Answer (score 0):

Will this be my answer :

```
 if(incomingPayload && incomingPayload.id && incomingPayload.id != 1234){
            incomingPayload.id = 1234;
            console.log('came here because different id params available');
        }
        else if (!incomingPayload.id) {
            incomingPayload.id = 1234;
            console.log('came here because no id params')
        }
```